# Angular 6 - Extract Integer and decimal for individual css formatting

Tags: angular

I would like to format a price in Angular so that the cents/decimal part is a superscript.

What would be the best Angular way to accomplish this from this base setup?

```
export class PriceComponent implements OnInit {
  price: number;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.price = 4567.89;
  }
}
```

price.component.html

```
<div class="price">
   <span class="dollar">{{price | [some pipe]}}</span>
   <span class="cents">{{price | [some other pipe]}}</span>
</div>
```

or in another way than using pipes...

Comment: What Do you want display exactly in HTML page???

Comment: It's better to round the points using javascript `floor` prototype

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipe like this.

```
@Pipe({name: 'split'})
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     *
     * @param value
     * @returns {number}
     */
    transform(value: number): number {
         let parts = number.toString().split('.');
         return `${parts[0]}<span>${parts[1]}</span>'`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pipe you can just pass the number to a function.

```
this.price = formatPrice( 4567.89 );

console.log(price);

formatPrice( price ) {
    let parts = price.toString().split('.');
    return parts[0] + '<span class="decimals">' + parts[1] + '</span>';
}
```